# xcode uploading to app store - No matching provisioning profiles found

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, provisioning-profile, signing

[image: error message that I'm receiving (image)]

I am having difficulty with uploading my app to the app store, I get the error "Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets: No matching provisioning profiles found for..." I'm not quite sure what this error means or how to fix it. I am somewhat new to xcode and the app store uploading process.

To my knowledge I've created everything necessary on the developer website to upload an app, and non of my certificated have expired. I've done some research and read other posts but so far everything others have suggested has not worked for me.

Hopefully I'm making a simple beginner's error that can be easily corrected.

Answer (score 0):

It shows the actual reason in the error message you posted your matching profiles do not contain the same entitlements as your app says is requesting.

Check your Project -> Capabilities and see which are set to on. Then on your provisioning portal check that your app has the same capabilities set.

If you don't need those capabilities simply turn them off and you should be able to build. If you do then you will need to set them up in the relevant App IDs on the provisioning portal. Identifiers-> App Ids -> app -> Edit

Some of these changes will require you to regenerate your provisioning profiles which you can do by clicking edit and then re-generating from the provisioning profiles section of your apple developer account.